# Problem calling OleDbConnection.GetSchema from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, oledb

I am making a PowerShell script to read schema information from Access databases. I am having trouble calling the [OleDbConnection.GetSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getschema?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-oledb-oledbconnection-getschema(system-string-system-string())) function with restrictions (for example to get only user tables, not system tables). Code that works in C# is:

```c#
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=filename.mdb");
connection.Open();
DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] {null, null, null, "TABLE"});
```

How can I correctly translate that last line to work in PowerShell?

My initial attempt was:

```
$schema = $connection.GetSchema('Tables', @($null, $null, $null, 'TABLE'))
```

This failed with an `OleDbException` with message: "The parameter is incorrect." I narrowed the problem down to the null values. Even passing a single null restriction:

```
$schema = $connection.GetSchema('Tables', @($null))
```

results in the same exception. Passing in a single null restriction should have the same effect as calling `GetSchema` without restrictions, which does work in PowerShell.

The exception I am getting is the same one you get if you pass an invalid value for one of the restrictions so I am assuming that `$null` is not being translated correctly somehow. For an Access database it is necessary for the first two restrictions (catalog and schema) to be null. Does anyone have an idea how to pass these null values correctly? Things I have tried include:

```
$connection.GetSchema('Tables',[string[]]@($null, $null, $null, 'TABLE'))

$connection.GetSchema('Tables',[string[]]@([string]$null, [string]$null, [string]$null, 'TABLE'))

[string[]] $restrictions = $null, $null, $null, 'TABLE'
$connection.GetSchema('Tables', $restrictions)
```

Also tried using ACE provider instead of JET. All attempts resulted in the same `OleDbException` with message: "The parameter is incorrect.".

Comment: If your database is made with Office 2007 or later you must use ACE (mdbx) and not JET (mdb),  You probably have more than one issue.  The version of ACE must match the version of office installed on your machine.  So Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is office version 12.  You may need to change to 16.  The filename for ACE is ACEDAO.DLL and should be in the program files folder.  Check the properties of the file and should indicate what version of Office it is using.  Change you connection string to match the version installed on machine.

Comment: Thanks but the databases I am working with are .mdb - the posted C# code works correctly using JET. I also already did try ACE in PowerShell just in case it worked differently somehow but the results are the same as JET - everything works OK except for the null values in the `restrictionValues` parameter of the `GetSchema` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Microsoft article helped me to figure it out:
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/schema-restrictions

The key is to declare the Restrictions string array upfront with the required length and next populate only the elements that need to be restricted/filtered. The remaining elements should not be initialized, not even with null values.

C# code from the article:

```
// Specify the restrictions.  
string[] restrictions = new string[4];  
restrictions[1] = "Sales";  
System.Data.DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
```

PowerShell:

```
$restrictions = New-Object -TypeName string[] -ArgumentList 4
$restrictions[2] = $tableName
$restrictions[3] = 'TABLE'
$result = $connection.GetSchema('Tables', $restrictions)
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

To natively connect to MSAccess using PowerShell, lots of available resources show you that. For example:

```
function Test-DBAccess
{
    Param
    (
            $fileName = 'C:\scripts\test.accdb'
    )
    
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$filename;Persist Security Info=False")
    $cmd=$conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText="Select * from table1"
    $conn.open()
    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
    $dt.Load($rdr)
    $dt
}
```

So, based on your C# code, leads to looking at the below MS Docs as well as the link you posted:

> ***GetSchema and Schema Collections***
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getschema-and-schema-collections
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/schema-restrictions

```
$connectionString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Temp\Test.accdb'

$oCon = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionString
$oCon.Open()


$oCon.GetSchema('Restrictions') | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name               MemberType            Definition
----               ----------            ----------
AcceptChanges      Method                void AcceptChanges()
BeginEdit          Method                void BeginEdit()
CancelEdit         Method                void CancelEdit()
ClearErrors        Method                void ClearErrors()
Delete             Method                void Delete()
EndEdit            Method                void EndEdit()
Equals             Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetChildRows       Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName, System.Data.Da...
GetColumnError     Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string GetColumnError(string columnName), string GetColumnError(System.Data.DataColumn ...
GetColumnsInError  Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()
GetHashCode        Method                int GetHashCode()
GetParentRow       Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName, System.Data.DataRo...
GetParentRows      Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName, System.Data....
GetType            Method                type GetType()
HasVersion         Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion version)
IsNull             Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(string columnName), bool IsNull(System.Data.DataColumn column), bool IsNull(System.Da...
RejectChanges      Method                void RejectChanges()
SetAdded           Method                void SetAdded()
SetColumnError     Method                void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string error), void SetColumnError(string columnName, string error), void SetColumnError(S...
SetModified        Method                void SetModified()
SetParentRow       Method                void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow), void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow, System.Data.DataRelation rel...
ToString           Method                string ToString()
Item               ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(string columnName) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(System.Dat...
CollectionName     Property              string CollectionName {get;set;}
RestrictionDefault Property              string RestrictionDefault {get;set;}
RestrictionName    Property              string RestrictionName {get;set;}
RestrictionNumber  Property              int RestrictionNumber {get;set;}
#>


$oCon.GetSchema('Restrictions') 
# Results
<#
CollectionName RestrictionName   RestrictionDefault RestrictionNumber
-------------- ---------------   ------------------ -----------------
Columns        TABLE_CATALOG                                        1
Columns        TABLE_SCHEMA                                         2
Columns        TABLE_NAME                                           3
Columns        COLUMN_NAME                                          4
Indexes        TABLE_CATALOG                                        1
Indexes        TABLE_SCHEMA                                         2
Indexes        INDEX_NAME                                           3
Indexes        TYPE                                                 4
Indexes        TABLE_NAME                                           5
Procedures     PROCEDURE_CATALOG                                    1
Procedures     PROCEDURE_SCHEMA                                     2
Procedures     PROCEDURE_NAME                                       3
Procedures     PROCEDURE_TYPE                                       4
Tables         TABLE_CATALOG                                        1
Tables         TABLE_SCHEMA                                         2
Tables         TABLE_NAME                                           3
Tables         TABLE_TYPE                                           4
Views          TABLE_CATALOG                                        1
Views          TABLE_SCHEMA                                         2
Views          TABLE_NAME                                           3
#>

$oCon.GetSchema('Tables') | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name              MemberType            Definition
----              ----------            ----------
AcceptChanges     Method                void AcceptChanges()
BeginEdit         Method                void BeginEdit()
CancelEdit        Method                void CancelEdit()
ClearErrors       Method                void ClearErrors()
Delete            Method                void Delete()
EndEdit           Method                void EndEdit()
Equals            Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetChildRows      Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName), ...
GetColumnError    Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string GetColumnError...
GetColumnsInError Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()
GetHashCode       Method                int GetHashCode()
GetParentRow      Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName), ...
GetParentRows     Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName), ...
GetType           Method                type GetType()
HasVersion        Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion version)
IsNull            Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(string columnName), ...
RejectChanges     Method                void RejectChanges()
SetAdded          Method                void SetAdded()
SetColumnError    Method                void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string error), ...
SetModified       Method                void SetModified()
SetParentRow      Method                void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow), ...
ToString          Method                string ToString()
Item              ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, ...
DATE_CREATED      Property              datetime DATE_CREATED {get;set;}
DATE_MODIFIED     Property              datetime DATE_MODIFIED {get;set;}
DESCRIPTION       Property              string DESCRIPTION {get;set;}
TABLE_CATALOG     Property              string TABLE_CATALOG {get;set;}
TABLE_GUID        Property              guid TABLE_GUID {get;set;}
TABLE_NAME        Property              string TABLE_NAME {get;set;}
TABLE_PROPID      Property              long TABLE_PROPID {get;set;}
TABLE_SCHEMA      Property              string TABLE_SCHEMA {get;set;}
TABLE_TYPE        Property              string TABLE_TYPE {get;set;} 
#>
```

So, as for your point...

> I am having trouble calling the OleDbConnection.GetSchema function
> with restrictions (for example to get only user tables, not system
> tables).

...this leads me to believe that this may help you.

***Get all tables:***

```
$connectionString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Temp\Test.accdb'

$oCon = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionString
$oCon.Open()

$oCon.GetSchema('Tables')
# Results
<#
TABLE_CATALOG : 
TABLE_SCHEMA  : 
TABLE_NAME    : MSysAccessStorage
TABLE_TYPE    : ACCESS TABLE
TABLE_GUID    : 
DESCRIPTION   : 
TABLE_PROPID  : 
DATE_CREATED  : 31-Jul-09 14:04:43
DATE_MODIFIED : 31-Jul-09 14:04:43

TABLE_CATALOG : 
TABLE_SCHEMA  : 
TABLE_NAME    : MSysACEs
TABLE_TYPE    : SYSTEM TABLE
TABLE_GUID    : 
DESCRIPTION   : 
TABLE_PROPID  : 
DATE_CREATED  : 31-Jul-09 14:04:43
DATE_MODIFIED : 31-Jul-09 14:04:43

...

TABLE_CATALOG : 
TABLE_SCHEMA  : 
TABLE_NAME    : Table1
TABLE_TYPE    : TABLE
TABLE_GUID    : 
DESCRIPTION   : 
TABLE_PROPID  : 
DATE_CREATED  : 09-Dec-22 17:38:28
DATE_MODIFIED : 09-Dec-22 17:38:51
#>
```

***Get user tables:***

```
$oCon.GetSchema('Tables') | 
Where-Object {$PSItem.TABLE_TYPE -eq 'TABLE'}

# Results
<#
TABLE_CATALOG : 
TABLE_SCHEMA  : 
TABLE_NAME    : Table1
TABLE_TYPE    : TABLE
TABLE_GUID    : 
DESCRIPTION   : 
TABLE_PROPID  : 
DATE_CREATED  : 09-Dec-22 17:38:28
DATE_MODIFIED : 09-Dec-22 17:38:51
#>
```

If the above does not work for your needs, then you can embed C# in PowerShell via the `Add-Type` cmdlet.

Comment: I was trying to keep my question brief but I guess I must have implied too much. I have already read a lot of the documentation and am having no trouble using the OleDb functions so far (even in Powershell) other than that one function call I asked about. I suppose I could do like you suggest and just load all the schema objects into PowerShell and do the filtering there. Probably wouldn't be as efficient, especially with columns, but would work. I had thought of Add-Type but the whole reason for doing this in PowerShell was to keep it simple for others to read/modify later.

Comment: Understood, but I'd personally not stress out about Add-Type, and that block/class really should have little reason to be altered. I would portend that using classes/Add-type stuff, would be the same as using any other Dll/Reference in higher-level languages. Similar to just using modules from Microsoft's powershellgallery.com.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem with

```
$connection.GetSchema('Tables', ($null, $null, $null, 'TABLE'))
```

is that when assigning `$null` to a string, PowerShell automatically converts it to `[string]::Empty` (see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616). So what PowerShell is actually executing is:

```
$connection.GetSchema('Tables', ([string]::Empty, [string]::Empty, [string]::Empty, 'TABLE'))
```

This causes an error because Access databases do not have catalogs or schemas, which are the first two restrictions. These two parameters must be null.

Apparently, PowerShell was designed to convert null strings to `[string]::Empty` in order to make error checking easier. But, there is a workaround specifically for passing null strings to .NET code: `[NullString]::Value`. (See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616#issuecomment-323530442). So, the following line does work:

```
$connection.GetSchema('Tables', ([NullString]::Value, [NullString]::Value, [NullString]::Value, 'TABLE'))
```

Thanks to [PickNick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289187/2293142) for noticing that assigning $null to a string is not the same thing as an un-initialized string in PowerShell!